# Using Mongoose pre save hook result in: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to hook into the save function in Mongoose to return an error to the client of a REST API if a certain condition is not met in the schema. I can't use a validator for this as the restriction is calculated over multiple fields of the schema.

I am trying to add a hook in the following style:

```
mySchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if(condition_is_not_met) {
    const err = new Error('Condition was not met');
    next(err);
  }
  next();
});
```

This throws an error when I try to make a call to the endpoint trying to insert an object that violates the condition checked for in the hook:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

I am guessing that this happens because execution continues on the route writing the header to send it to the client.

```
router.post('/mySchema', returnType, (req, res) => {
  const s = new mySchema(req.body);
  s.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      const msg = { message: 'Could not add', error: err }; // This is returned to the caller
      res.status(500);
      res.send(msg);
    }
    res.status(200);
    res.send(s);
  });
});
```

How can i fix this issue? I have been searching quite a bit but the topics I found so far do not help me to solve my issue. They only helped me to identify the cause without offering a working solution.

Comment: Did you try to put an else branch for the status 200?

Comment: I mean even if the object you are sending is invalid the execution will still reach the response for a success thus respondig 2 times..

Comment: @Teebo just tried that but that doesn't fix it either. The error is not thrown actually if I leave out the hook. Just by adding the hook the error is introduced. It must have something to do with some stuff walking out of sync but I can't identify what exactly.

Comment: @Teebo I was incorrect that did solve it. I was thrown off as I was overwriting the error set in the hook. Need to solve that to guarantee your solution to the problem works. If you post your solution for others in the future facing the same issue I can mark it as the solution after I figured out how to prevent overwriting the error as set by the hook.

Comment: Add return to here:    res.status(500);  return res.send(msg);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try having an else branch for the success response? Since even if the object is invalid the success response will still be executed. Try it like below

```
router.post("/mySchema", returnType, (req, res) => {
  const s = new mySchema(req.body);
  s.save(err => {
    if (err) {
      const msg = { message: "Could not add", error: err };
      res.status(500);
      res.send(msg);
    } else {
      res.status(200);
      res.send(s);
    }
  });
});
```

Pardon my code formatting, I am AFK

Comment: You're pardoned. Doing this solved the issue but required the setting of the error to be changed to: const msg = { message: (err.message) ? err.message : 'Could not add', error: err };

Comment: No worry, I formatted. Also we can use one line like this:  res.status(500).send(msg);  to shorten code.

Comment: @Ruud, I am so glad it gave some light to solving the issue!

Comment: @SuleymanSah I know I can chain the methods but I need to make sure other can easily follow execution in the future. Separating each action into it's own line makes the code more readable to some.

Comment: I'm curious, the error is still  throwing as 500 status in node console, but with this I can return a 400 status to the client, is this fairly correct or there's another way to do this?